# Ballerina - How to use parameter/variable value as key in a map?

Tags: key, maps, ballerina

```ballerina
string key = "a";
map<string> maps = {
    key: "b"
};
```

Is there a way to add the value of the parameter for the key in the above instance?

```ballerina
map<string> maps = {
    "a": "b"
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Computed Field Key,

```ballerina
string key = "a";
map<string> maps = {
    [key]: "b"
    //Variable name should be surrounded with square brackets
};
```

Any expression can be specified within square brackets. For more information, see [Computed field key Ballerina By Example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/computed-field-key/)